# unable to add private IP to Appgateway in azure using terraform or azcli

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cloud-services, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to add a private IP to app gateway in azure using terraform, I am using terraform to all provision the infrastructure in azure, I am able to add public IP, but unable to add private IP.
Any leads please

Comment: Do you want to add private Ip to the app gateway backend or frontend? Could you show your code?

Comment: I want to add private IP  to Frontend appgateway

Comment: If you have any questions, please let me know or if this reply could solve your question, please accept this answer via click the checkmark(toggle it from greyed out to filled in) underneath the vote buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add private IP to Frontend, you just need to add another  [frontend_ip_configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/application_gateway.html#frontend_ip_configuration-1) block with private IP information in your code.

Here is a working example on my side.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "example-test"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {
  name                = "example-network"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  address_space       = ["10.254.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "frontend" {
  name                 = "frontend"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}"
  address_prefix       = "10.254.0.0/24"
}


resource "azurerm_subnet" "backend" {
  name                 = "backend"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}"
  address_prefix       = "10.254.2.0/24"
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "test" {
  name                = "example-pip"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku = "Standard"
}




# since these variables are re-used - a locals block makes this more maintainable
locals {
  backend_address_pool_name      = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}-beap"
  frontend_port_name             = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}-feport"
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}-feip"
  http_setting_name              = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}-be-htst"
  listener_name                  = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}-httplstn"
  request_routing_rule_name      = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}-rqrt"
  redirect_configuration_name    = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}-rdrcfg"
}




resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "network" {
  name                = "example-appgateway"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"

  sku {
    name     = "WAF_v2"
    tier     = "WAF_v2"
    capacity = 2
  }

  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "my-gateway-ip-configuration"
    subnet_id = "${azurerm_subnet.frontend.id}"
  }


  frontend_port {
    name = "${local.frontend_port_name}"
    port = 80
  }

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "${local.frontend_ip_configuration_name}"
    public_ip_address_id = "${azurerm_public_ip.test.id}"
  }


 frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "${local.frontend_ip_configuration_name}-private"
    subnet_id = "${azurerm_subnet.frontend.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    private_ip_address = "10.254.0.10"
  }



  backend_address_pool {
    name = "${local.backend_address_pool_name}"
  }

  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = "${local.http_setting_name}"
    cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
    path                  = "/path1/"
    port                  = 80
    protocol              = "Http"
    request_timeout       = 1
  }

  http_listener {
    name                           = "${local.listener_name}"
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = "${local.frontend_ip_configuration_name}"
    frontend_port_name             = "${local.frontend_port_name}"
    protocol                       = "Http"
  }

  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = "${local.request_routing_rule_name}"
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = "${local.listener_name}"
    backend_address_pool_name  = "${local.backend_address_pool_name}"
    backend_http_settings_name = "${local.http_setting_name}"
  }
}
```

Result:
[image]